# Very Slow Download speed in terminal

Tags: command-line, internet, elementary, download-speed

The download speed in Terminal is very slow. about 40kBytes. But the speed in the browser works fine
I have chosen the best server but I still get the problem
by the way loot at the output of tracepath 1.1.1.1 output if it helps:[image]

Comment: How are you testing download speed? And which speed are you expecting? How are you connected to the internet?

Comment: for example, I do sudo apt install vlc  and download speed is about 40KBytes it is supposed to download much faster as I experienced it before,I am connecting via modem td-lte

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](//askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS/release, but you have tagged an off-topic OS (*which is also the name of an icon/window theme used by Xubuntu (XFCE) but your image doesn't look like XFCE*).  Please provide release details https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: it is elementary os

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. Official flavors are Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu-MATE, Ubuntu-Budgie, Ubuntu-Kylin, Ubuntu-Studio, Ubuntu... ie easy to spot having Ubuntu in their name, and downloaded from ubuntu.com (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic offers alternate SE sites if you don't want to use an Elementary forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting fast speed in the browser and only slow speed for installing packages, the network mirror might be having a problem.
You can use `netselect` package, as it guarantees the fastest mirror selection.

The `netselect` package is not available within Ubuntu's standard repository by default, so we will need to download it from Debian stable repository. So, run these commands

```
wget http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/netselect/netselect_0.3.ds1-26_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i netselect_0.3.ds1-26_amd64.deb
```

Once you have the `netselect` command available on your Ubuntu system use it to locate the fastest mirror based on the lowest ICMP latency. The `netselect` output will be relative to your location. The output will show the top 20 apt Ubuntu mirrors ( if available ):

```
sudo netselect -s 20 -t 40 $(wget -qO - mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt)
```

Manually alter your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to reflect the above `netselect` results

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or use `sed` command, where the lower score number on the left represents a higher mirror transfer rate. Example:

```
sudo sed -i 's/http:\/\/us.archive.ubuntu.com\/ubuntu\//http:\/\/ubuntu.uberglobalmirror
```